# i get Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_theme_support()

Tags: wordpress

i get fatal error on my wordpress site,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_theme_support() in /home/globalunairac/public_html/wp-includes/block-patterns.php:9 Stack trace: #0 /home/globalunairac/public_html/wp-settings.php(320): require() #1 /home/globalunairac/public_html/wp-config.php(97): require_once('/home/globaluna...') #2 /home/globalunairac/public_html/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/globaluna...') #3 /home/globalunairac/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/globaluna...') #4 /home/globalunairac/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/globaluna...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/globalunairac/public_html/wp-includes/block-patterns.php on line 9

Notice: Function is_embed was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/globalunairac/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5833

Notice: Function is_search was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/globalunairac/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5833
There has been a critical error on this website.
```

what the solution of this issue? i tried rename theme and plugin folder and still didn't work

i tried rename theme and plugin folder and still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

**Please complete the following steps:**

1. Go to the plugin settings page;
2. Open "Custom Code" tab, mark "Activate custom PHP code" checkbox in "PHP" section and insert the following code:

```
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' ); function theme_setup() { add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

3. Save changes.

Comment: the problem is i cannot logged into my wordpress dashboard, how if i custom code from the directory file manager? can you show me the directory

Comment: which file should i insert that code?

Comment: you can do from hosting file manager and go into themes and add in child theme function.php file

Comment: still not working

Comment: you have tried to activate another theme?